# Delayed semantic actions in Bison?

Tags: bison

For example, I have the following syntax with actions:

```
StmtList: Stmt
        | StmtList Stmt
        ;

Stmt: StmtOne { ActionOne }
    | StmtTwo { ActionTwo }
    ;
```

The problem is ActionOne should be done before ActionTwo (for some reason), but the user can write StmtOne and StmtTwo in any order. Any idea on how to do that? I once thought [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), but not really sure if it works.

Comment: You've used the alternation operator (pipe) in your grammar.  That means that only `StmtOne` or `StmtTwo` is a valid `Prog`, not both.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I modify the syntax to clarify my intention, sorry for the confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to this sort of problem is:

1. Use the generated parser to build an AST
2. Walk the AST and perform actions as necessary.

In effect, that delays all actions until the entire parse is complete, when all information is known; furthermore, the walk can be done in any order you find convenient or necessary (or even multiple times).

I suppose that's an instance of the Command Pattern. I'd say it was an instance of a Compile pattern, which is what `bison` is designed for. However, unlike some other parser generators, `bison` doesn't provide shorthand notation for AST building.

Here's a conceptual example:

```
prog   : actions         { do_action1($1->action1); do_action2($1->action2); }

actions: %empty          { $$ = actionLists(); }
       | actions action1 { append($1->action1, $2); $$ = $1; }
       | actions action2 { append($1->action2, $2); $$ = $1; }
       ;
```

Comment: Building AST is a little overkill for my simple syntax, although it's the right approach. I choose to parse the text multiple time, and use some tricks to enable actions orderly.